# Cannot read property 'length' of null: using `sender.set_selectedToggleStateIndex(val)` within a nested function that is used as a radprompt callback

Tags: telerik

I'm getting "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null**" when calling `sender.set_selectedToggleStateIndex(val)` within a **nested function** that is used as a **radprompt callback**.

**sender is a radbutton** (ButtonType = Toggle; ToggleType = CustomToggle).

*Although this may not be relevant: the radButton is initiated in a radgrid via Custom GridTemplateColumn.*

```
OnToggleValueChangingResultHandler = function (sender, e, args, result) {
    if ((result) ? result.isValid : false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
            radprompt(result.message, OnToggleValueChangingPromptCallBackFn, 400, 350, null, result.title || "Prompt - Override", false);
        } else {
            radalert(result.message || "Internal Error Occurred!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Error", null, null);
        }
        return false;
    }
    function OnToggleValueChangingPromptCallBackFn(promptArgs) {
        promptArgs = promptArgs || { "override": false, "note": "" };
        if (promptArgs.override && promptArgs.note.length > 0) {
            args.Override = promptArgs.override;
            args.OverrideNote = promptArgs.note;
            var result = Paysheet.XHR.POST(args._uri, args);
            result.isValid = true;
            if ((result) ? result.isValid : false) {
                // $find(sender.id).set_selectedToggleStateIndex(args.newIndex);
                sender.set_selectedToggleStateIndex(args.newIndex);

            } else {
                if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
                    radalert(result.message || "Override request denied!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Override Denied", null, null);
                } else {
                    radalert(result.message || "Internal Error Occurred!", 400, 350, result.title || "Alert - Error", null, null);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // ensuring the control retains the same value; for the prompt is async;
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern seems to work properly with a radcombobox and a series of radtextboxes. Additionally, the eventArgs seem more robust.

I suspect this issue is rooted in ClientState persistence and referencing: controlStates and/or viewState being lossed.

If I attempt to call `sender.get_selectedToggleState()` or `sender.get_selectedToggleStateIndex()` in the PromptCallbackFn, I get an error stating **this._functionality** is undefined. _functionality seems to be in regards to controlstate.

**Note:**

`sender.get_clientStateFieldID()` returns the ClientID properly, but `$find(sender.get_clientStateFieldID())` returns `null`.

`sender.get_toggleStateData()` returns the data properly. but
`sender.get_toggleStates()` returns `null`.

`sender.get_parent()` returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be to set the `Autopostback = false` of the **RadButton**.

such a minor oversight.

the postback went unnoticed for me because of the nature of these controls.